# How to check if an instance of a class exists based on its name

Tags: python, dictionary, oop, python-class

I have an application that reads bluetooth advertisements from sensors and does stuff.

Currently, I use a dict to manage instances of the sensors and attributes of them. I have a bunch of functions that I call to do stuff based on the details of the bluetooth advertisements.

I am interested in switching from a dict to creating a class called Sensors. Having functions/methods within the class itself will clean up my code a lot (make it more readable) and set me up better for adding new features.

When a new advertisement comes in, the first step I do is to check whether it's from a sensor I've seen before. This is simple with a dict using

```
newAdvertisement = {"name": "sensor1", "attribute": "value"}
sensor = newAdvertisement['name']
if sensor in sensorDict
    ...
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to do something similar with instances of a class. If I read a string value from the advertisement, how can I check if there is an instance of my class with that name?

I've tried to work out a way to use isInstance with something like this:

```
newAdvertisement = {"name": "sensor1", "attribute": "value"}
sensor = newAdvertisement['name']
if isInstance(sensor, Sensor):
    ...
```

But line 2 sets the variable 'sensor' to the string 'sensor1', so this checks if that string is an instance of Sensor (which it is of course, not). What I want is to check if there is an instance of Sensor called sensor1.

I've also tried to create a list of instances like so:

```
sensor1 = Sensor(name='sensor1', attribute='value')
sensor2 = Sensor(name='sensor2', attribute='value')
sensorList = [sensor1, sensor2]

newAdvertisement = {"name": "sensor1", "attribute": "value"}
sensor = newAdvertisement['name']
if sensor in sensorList:
    ...
```

But again, I'm comparing the string 'sensor' to a list of objects, so it's never going to be there.

Does it make sense to do this? Can I do it cleanly? Is it useful to have my own class in this code?

Comment: Instances of a class do not inherently give you any way to access them by name.  Keeping a dict with the sensor names as keys would still be the standard solution, you'd just have `Sensor` instances as the dict values (instead of whatever you had before).

Comment: "What I want is to check if there is an instance of Sensor called sensor1." What does this mean? In your own words, how can I say that "instances of Sensor" are "called" anything at all? Are you talking about the **variable names**? Because any given object - whether it's an instance of your own class, a string, or anything else - can have **any number of** such names, **including zero**.

Comment: That said: if you want to be able to use a dictionary to look up an instance of a class, then **put the instances of the class into the dictionary**. The reason that you get strings right now is because that's what you put in. I'm voting to close the question because what you are trying to do indeed makes no sense at all, and thus there isn't a meaningful question underneath.

Comment: _What I want is to check if there is an instance of Sensor called sensor1_ Why do you care what the variable is named?

Comment: I understand that it doesn't make sense to check if there is an instance "called sensor1". That is why I gave more context to the question to convey what I am trying to find out. I am used to referring to dict entries by their key, so I can check if that key exists. If I switch to using a class, I am trying to figure out how to do the same - check if I have created it already. Barmar provided exactly what I was looking for below so I marked it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing that does this automatically.

Your class can maintain a dictionary of all the instances.

```
import weakref

class Sensor:
    sensor_dict = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

    def __init__(self, name, attribute)
        self.sensor_dict[name] = self
        self.name = name
        self.attribute = attribute
```

Then you can do

```
if sensor in Sensor.sensor_dict:
```

I've used a `WeakValueDictionary` so the elements will be removed automatically when the `Sensor` instances are GC'ed.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of achieving this.  One would be to perform some list comprehension to your list when checking to see if the sensor is present in the list of sensors.

For example:

```
sensor1 = Sensor(name='sensor1', attribute='value')
sensor2 = Sensor(name='sensor2', attribute='value')
sensorList = [sensor1, sensor2]

newAdvertisement = {"name": "sensor1", "attribute": "value"}
sensor = newAdvertisement['name']
if sensor in [i.name for i in sensorList]:
    ...
```

Another way would be to overwrite the `__eq__` method in your sensor class.

For example:

```
class Sensor:
    def __init__(self, name, attribute):
        self.name = name
        self.attribute = attribute

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other == self.name

sensor1 = Sensor(name='sensor1', attribute='value')
sensor2 = Sensor(name='sensor2', attribute='value')

sensorList = [sensor1, sensor2]

if "sensor1" in sensorList:
    print("found")
```

In the example above, "found" is successfully printed because when you use the `in` keyword, python checks for equality on all of the elements in the container.  Since the `__eq__` method is set to compare to the sensor name, once it reaches the sensor with that name it returns True.